# Calling a method after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying Redux in a project.
I have a list of countries, all of which have a price, and I want to select the countries with prices between `minPrice` and `maxPrice` values. I am doing that in this method:

```
  filterPrice: function(minPrice, maxPrice) {
    var newCountries = [];
    _.forEach(this.props.countries, function(country) {
        var price = country["price"];
        if(minPrice <= price && price <= maxPrice) {
            newCountries.push(country);
        }
    });
    this.setState({countries: newCountries});
  }
```

Now, I would like this method to be called somehow by the Redux architecture.

I have this reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  minPrice: 0,
  maxPrice: Constants.PRICE_RANGE
};


export default function PriceReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case types.UPDATE_MAX:
      return {
        maxPrice: action.maxPrice
      }
    case types.UPDATE_MIN:
      return {
        minPrice: action.minPrice
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And these actions:

```
export const updateMax = (maxPrice) => {
  return {
    type: types.UPDATE_MAX,
    maxPrice: maxPrice
  };
}

export const updateMin = (minPrice) => {
  return {
    type: types.UPDATE_MIN,
    minPrice: minPrice
  };
}
```

I am creating a store like this:

```
const store = createStore(PriceReducer);
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
store.dispatch({type: types.UPDATE_MIN, minPrice: 10});
```

So how can I call `filterPrice`?
Or if I can't call it, how do I change the state?

Comment: The structure there seems a bit confusing.  You're calling `this.setState()` in your `filterPrice` function - is that intended to be inside a React component?  Are you wanting to call that after a Redux action is dispatched and the store is updated?  Or are you wanting to use that as part of your reducer logic?

Comment: Yes, that's inside a React component. I would like that method to be called once I change either `minPrice` or `maxPrice`. Or if it can't be called, I would like the changes it does to be executed.

Comment: is your component connected to redux?

Comment: If by connected, you mean having this around my `App`: `<Provider store={store}>
     <App>
  </Provider>` then yes.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist  mapping the redux store to the componet using connect() basically wrapping the component with `connect(function(store){return store})(component)`

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use redux in the common way, you need to keep all you state in redux, to make it a single source of truth. So, the first thing you should do is to put you country list in redux. Then, if you need some calculated properties, like, countries filtered by price, it's time to make selectors, using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library. Also, it's a good idea to read [corresponding section](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) of redux documentation.

In the end, you architecture will look like this:

- redux keeps `minPrice`, `maxPrice` and `countries`
- your container component use selectors to retrive data from state, calculate derived data and pass it to presentational components

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't use `this.state` at all?

Comment: @octavian Yes. Actually, you should always try to keep React component stateless, as far as it is possible. When you describe your derived data as a pure function of props, you don't need to care about updating your component state in time - it's React main responsibility. You can do it using `connect` function and `reselect` library for this, our use @Mike approach, it doesn't matter - the key point here to keep it pure.

Comment: @NikolaiMavrenkov: "Always have stateless components" is a good _principle_, but that's not a hard rule.  Per the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state , there are times when you'd want to keep some data in component state.

Comment: @markerikson Yes, you're right, that's why I wrote *try*)

Answer (score 0):

Redux should be the source of state in the component.  You should be able to filter the list and changes to minPrice and maxPrice should trigger your rerender.

```
filteredByPrice: function() {
   return this.props.countries.filter(function(country){
      return this.props.minPrice <= this.props.country.price && 
        this.props.country.price <= this.props.maxPrice
   }
}
... 
render: function(){
  return ....
      {this.filteredByPrice().map(function(country){
        return <div> {country.name} </div>
      })} 
  ....
```